# client not defined in discord bot module

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

i'm new to any sort of programming. in my discord bot, the main file looks for modules to execute commands.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

require('dotenv').config();
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const botCommands = require('./commands');

Object.keys(botCommands).map(key => {
  bot.commands.set(botCommands[key].name, botCommands[key]);
});

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

bot.login(TOKEN);

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
  const args = msg.content.split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  console.info(`Called command: ${command}`);

  if (!bot.commands.has(command)) return;

  try {
    bot.commands.get(command).execute(msg, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    msg.reply('Check it out! You *failed*.');
  }
});
```

one of the commands is supposed to send a message to a certain channel after triggered:

```
module.exports ={
    name: '!start',
    description: 'Starts the killing game',
    execute(msg, args) {
        client.on('ready', client => {
        client.channels.cache.get('724557257484009516').send('The killing game is about to start!');
        });
    },
};
```

but it comes up with this error:

```
ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.execute (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\commands\game-start.js:5:3)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\index.js:28:31)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
Called command: <@253506821438832640>,
```

how do i fix it?

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem, so others can see it too

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the client variable from your index.js file to your command file, also do not put an event listener inside a command, very bad idea, instead do something like this:

```
execute(msg, args) {
    Let guild = msg.client.guilds.cache.get(‘ID of the guild in which the channel is in);
    guild.channels.cache.get('724557257484009516').send('The killing game is about to start!');
},
```

I've used `msg.client` because, from discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client)
: `message.client` The client that instantiated this message, so your bot.

Comment: okay i tried this out but now i got a different error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.execute (D:\drpa-bot\big bin\commands\game-start.js:5:31)

Comment: My bad, check the edited answer, you first need to get the guild in which the channel is in, then get the channel from that guild